# How to ask file name path in .net core3 WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.0

Is there a way to replace the OpenFileDialog and the SaveFileDialog in WPF .net core 3.0 ?
Or we need to develop a window to replace them?
Thanks